# Make EditText pass focus back to parent layout when finished editing.

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have a linear layout in a fragment with a bunch of checkboxes and various edittext widgets inside it. Basically like a quiz. A bunch of multiple choice(checkboxes) and a dozen short answer(edittexts) questions.

What I would like is for users to be able to click an edittext, type in an answer, then press DONE or click anywhere else on the layout and have the widget lose focus and the keyboard hide. Currently I am overriding the `setOnEditorActionListener` and `setOnFocusChangeListener` methods of each edittext to give focus back to a main layout, and hide the keyboard respectively. Here is the code for an edittext instance called "input_7d":

```
    final EditText input_7d = (EditText) thisview.findViewById(R.id.txtinput_7d);
    final LinearLayout parentLayout = (LinearLayout) thisview.findViewById(R.id.main_layout);

    input_7d.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                parentLayout.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    input_7d.setOnFocusChangeListener(new TextView.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(!hasFocus){
                InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(parentLayout.getWindowToken(),InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
        }
    });
```

This is annoying to do for every edittext I add, and it means editing lots of code if I remove them or add more in the future. What I would like to do is have a custom edittext class that can return focus to it's parent view/layout and hide the keyboard, then use that instead of the built in edittext. I'm very new to this and I haven't been able to find a way for a custom edittext to pass focus back to it's parent layout. Is there a better way to get a bunch of edittexts to all have this behavior and not have it all "hardcoded" into my fragment class?

Comment: I know that it is possible to define a custom View in Android where you also can define the standard behaviour of the custom View. I would suggest to give that a try.

Comment: @Stitchblade Yeah I ended up doing that, as I showed in my answer below. Unfortunately I couldn't figure out how to pass focus to another view/layout from inside the custom view. But at least my custom view saves 40 lines of code for every editText I add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I could not find a way to have a edittext pass focus back to it's parent layout from inside the view itself. So instead I have opted to just disable focusable property of it when it

1) It loses focus (user clicked outside the view on something focusable, ie. The parent layout)

2) Finishes it's edit(user presses Done action on soft keyboard)

Surprisingly neither of these actions by default remove focus and the cursor from a default editText. At least not inside my scroll views.

So I added these lines to a custom view(myEditText) that extends the editText view:

```
this.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        if(actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            myEditText.setFocusable(false);
            myEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);

        }
        return false;
    }
});
this.setOnFocusChangeListener(new TextView.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        if(!hasFocus){
            myEditText.setFocusable(false);
            myEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
            hideKeyboardFrom(context, v);
        }
    }
});
this.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        myEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        myEditText.setFocusable(true);
        return false;
    }
});
```

I find it really annoying that to get simple functionality like not having the cursor blinking at me always or having the view not take focus when changing fragments and such you have to do such a weird workaround. Making a view unfocusable unless it's focused in which case it is focusable but only until it isn't focused again just seems dumb. Still wondering if there is a better way to do this for a large number of edits in one layout.

Answer (score 0):

you can set a touch listener for the root layout and then remove the focus whenever not needed for the view

```
     findViewById(R.id.rootView).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         v.requestFocusFromTouch() //check for y
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Unfortunately that will leave the soft keyboard visible and doesn't solve the issue of returning focus to the layout after a user presses the DONE key. So I still need to detect DONE as-well as try to close the keyboard on every touch of the rootView. I already have the root view set to be clickable in the xml which is basically what your code is doing.